# WebView loading blank screen in devices but working fine in emulator

Tags: android, webview

Enabled these two options for mywebview,

```
webV.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webV.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear from your question where you are getting the blank screen, whether you are getting it while page load or while moving to some other page.

Try removing `super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error)`, it would solve your issue.

Comment: in onpagefinished url is loading .. after onpagefinished i am getting white screen url is not loading . for that url i got SSL exception but i am handling it using handler.proceed

Comment: Try removing super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error) it would solve your issue.

Comment: Funny... your answer should be a comment, and your comment should be an answer!

Comment: @BobMalooga i don't have enough points to comment on anybody's post that's why i have to go this way.

Comment: yeah I agree with Bob, its not a answer its a comment

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav if i had points to comment i would have done that but i tried to help her that's why wrote it there.

Comment: OK, I changed your answer to a real answer, by adding your comment to that.

Answer (score 0):

With out the full code it's very difficult to tell whats wrong in your code, as for as am using the below code to achieve web view please cross check your code with this

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    } });

webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

try adding this code snippet also (not tested it)

```
webview.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

please check you have added the permissions also

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Already tried these options .. didn't work

Comment: are you using WebView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) before the URL loading